# Difficulty parsing XML with SQL Server TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm having some difficulties in parsing some XML into the table format that I need. Here is an example of the xml I will be receiving

```
<p>8abbdcf1-eff2-4b26-b905-343298338954</p>
<d>
    <id>172fcf08-79d6-467a-a40e-362583683680</id>
    <id>2149987c-1311-4ad0-b8bb-362477435274</id>
</d>
```

There will always be 1 element in "p" and there can be any number of IDs in "d".

I want the results to apply "p" to every id in "d". I've looked around and tried to understand the way xml parsing works but have been having some difficulties. My results are usually either 1 record with a single ID or 2 records (the number of elements in "d") but the value returned is null. As I've not managed to get the list of IDs yet I have not moved on to applying P to this.

Below is my most recent effort:

```
SET @InputXML = 
    '
    <p>8abbdcf1-eff2-4b26-b905-343298338954</p>
    <d>
        <id>172fcf08-79d6-467a-a40e-362583683680</id>
        <id>2149987c-1311-4ad0-b8bb-362477435274</id>
    </d>
    '
SELECT list.d.value('id[1]','nvarchar(100)') AS ID
FROM @InputXML.nodes('/d') AS list(d)
```

Hoped for result would be:

```
p                                     |ID
8abbdcf1-eff2-4b26-b905-343298338954  |172fcf08-79d6-467a-a40e-362583683680
8abbdcf1-eff2-4b26-b905-343298338954  |2149987c-1311-4ad0-b8bb-362477435274
```

Comment: can you edit the question with the expected result in table format

Comment: will you consider not to parse XML with TSQL ? it'll be easier if you work with server-side languages, such as JSP, ASP.NET or PHP

Comment: I've added the expected result.

Comment: Raptor, no it's not currently possible to do it another way. however I may be able to influence a change in the xml format if that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `/id` to your nodes function in order to get a new row for each id, then you can use `.value('.','nvarchar(100)')` to get the inner text of each `id` node. This appears to work as expected:

```
DECLARE @InputXML XML = 
    '<p>8abbdcf1-eff2-4b26-b905-343298338954</p>
    <d>
        <id>172fcf08-79d6-467a-a40e-362583683680</id>
        <id>2149987c-1311-4ad0-b8bb-362477435274</id>
    </d>';

SELECT  p = @InputXML.value('p[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
        id = list.d.value('.','nvarchar(100)')
FROM    @InputXML.nodes('d/id') AS list(d);
```

Comment: Hi Gareth, that works thank you very much. I had /id in the nodes function at one point but at that point i was returning nulls for each row. it was the '.' part that i did not know about. Thank you again